# Creating a custom millisecond-based chrono clock that increments counters, and resets every year?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++-chrono

I'm starting out with a basic task in C++, coming from Pascal and Lua. I picked this as it seems simple enough, and useful for the project I'm working on.

I need to create a millisecond timer that starts at 0 for everything; Year 0, month 0, week 0, day 0. It will also run at a faster timescale than real life; every second that passes is 20 seconds for this timer. Which should be easy? Just multiply each ms by 20 and save that.

As the timer progresses, increment various counters that track seconds/minutes/hours/days/weeks/months/seasons/years passed. And after a year has passed, reset the timer back to 0ms and continue incrementing.

I will also be stopping, saving, loading, resuming. That bit I'll be able to handle, as I have access to a MySQL database to take care of serializing data. I'm just perplexed by **std:chrono**, and couldn't understand how to make my own arbitrary starting time and reference date.

Don't have any code yet, but here's the layout for the C++ file:

```cpp
namespace FyTyGameTime
{

    //Number of realtime milliseconds for each timescale second.
    uint32_t TimeScaleMsMult = 20;

    //Current iteration's total number of milliseconds
    uint32_t TimeScaleCounter = 0;

    //Total accumulated time
    uint32_t TimeScaleMinutes = 0;
    uint32_t TimeScaleHours = 0;
    uint32_t TimeScaleDays = 0;
    uint32_t TimeScaleWeeks = 0;
    uint32_t TimeScaleMonths = 0;
    uint32_t TimeScaleSeasons = 0;
    uint32_t TimeScaleYears = 0; //Number of years passed since timer started

    //Current iteration's counters.
    //Current start date is 01/01/0000 7am
    uint32_t TimeScaleCurrentSecond = 0; //0-86399, Resets every day
    uint32_t TimeScaleCurrentMinute = 420; //0-1339, Resets every day
    uint32_t TimeScaleCurrentHour = 7; //0-23, Resets every day
    uint32_t TimeScaleCurrentDay = 0; //0-6, Resets every week
    uint32_t TimeScaleCurrentWeek = 0; //0-3, Resets every month
    uint32_t TimeScaleCurrentMonth = 0; //0-11, Resets every year
    uint32_t TimeScaleCurrentSeason = 0; //0-3, Resets every year

    uint32_t TimeScaleCurrentYear = 0; //Starting year, incremeneted every year. !Does not reset!

    uint32_t RealTimeToTimescale(uint32_t iMilliseconds)
    {
        return uint32_t(iMilliseconds * TimeScaleMsMult);
    }

    bool SaveTimescale()
    {
        //
    }

    void LoadTimescale()
    {
        //
    }

    bool ResetTimescale()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Any help and clarification on std::chrono is appreciated, thank you. C++ Is quite a bit more terse than the languages I usually use and feel comfortable with.

edit: <strike>From what I've been able to read, **std::chrono::steady_clock** is the way to go. But it doesn't have any member functions to pause, resume, and to modify its values?</strike>

> The time points of this clock cannot decrease as physical time moves forward and the time between ticks of this clock is constant. This clock is not related to wall clock time (for example, it can be time since last reboot), and is most suitable for measuring intervals.

The only member function it has is `now()`...

edit2: No, that is still based on some external timer. While I need to increment every ms. It seems like the three clocks provided for chrono are for duration checks, rather than actually used to do something every time interval?

Comment: Have decided if you are going to use Event-Driven or Polling?  IMHO, a millisecond clock may not be accurate, depending on the operating system.  Windows is not guaranteed to maintain millisecond accuracy.

Comment: A worthy project, but you have selected a rather arcane part of c++ as your starting point.

Comment: All date libraries/os interfaces define an epoch that they are based on, so for that part, simply choose your delta from the reference time. As for all your counters, you don't really need most of them because each tickover is a simple modulus calculation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't actually know. I thought std::chrono had that sorted. If I was to pick, event-driven would be best as it's not a constant update. But the events do have to be triggered somehow, which sounds a bit complex for a baby-bird project.

Comment: @PaulDempsey IIRC std::chrono uses UNIX 1970 as the starting point. I suppose one way is to somehow fake a start date of 1970? But actually doing this is the bit I'm lost on. The docs aren't exactly clear and simple for the uninitiated.

Comment: By event driven, the "system" generates an event every millisecond.  For example, on our embedded system, we have an interrupt handler that is activated every millisecond.  So if you wanted to redraw a time widget, you would put a function call in the interrupt handler to call your widget repaint function.  This is another reason that I believe that 1ms is a tight constraint (and difficult for some OSes to maintain).

Comment: For example, using Windows, you would need Windows to send an 1ms event message to your program,  Your program catches the event then performs a repaint or refresh on your clock widget.